# Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator

Tags: windows, permission-denied

Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator.

I get this error when I try to save anything in my external drive.
I only able to copy and cut file.
(only transfer file ,not able to save after editing file)

I have tried with other pendive or hardrive same issue but with same pendrive or hardrive I am able to edit and save file in my friends pc.

I contact with microsoft and they were not able to solve this issue , they said try to reinstall windows or there might be an hardware issue .

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour].  For app and OS usage you should ask this at [su] not here.  Wild guess: you did something to make administrator the owner of the external dtive so a normal user has no write permission.  Wild guess 2: this is a managed computer where work or school has installed software that controls what you can do.  Wild guess 3: an infection of some kind.